# PHP APC only caching opcodes

Tags: php, caching, apc

I recently installed and configured PHP APC on a CentOS 6.3 box running in conjuction with PHP 5.3.3 and Apache2. It seems that APC is only caching opcodes (or files that are loaded) and not running (or maybe it is) the multiple apc_store functions in my code. I thought that it may be that it is running out of memory so I set the shm_size to something rediculous that I knew would compensate (512M) and that didnt work. I even turned off cache_by_default so that it would stop caching opcodes but that didnt work either (it just didnt cache anything). So what could be the problem? TYA

Comment: If you apc_store() and apc_fetch() in the same request does it work?  The next request apc_fetch() returns false?

Comment: Also `php_sapi_name()` will tell you if you're using fastcgi, a common reason for your problem.

Comment: I tried running a simple script that stores and fetches in the same request, but to no avail. No store, no fetch. Also `php_sapi_name()` does not output anything (white page)

Comment: Did you echo it?  What about `echo PHP_SAPI;`?  Also what are the return values of `apc_store()` and `apc_fetch()`? Both false?

Comment: ok, store and fetch in the same request works, but it doesn't seem to remain in the cache. `php_sapi_name()` ouputs `apache2handler`